# How can I get track length (min/sec) from Gracenote's Web API?

Tags: php, gracenote

I'm using [php-gracenote](https://github.com/richadams/php-gracenote) to access Gracenote's Web API. Can please someone explain how to get each track length in min/sec when searching for a album. Is it possible? Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Generally speaking, track durations aren't returned by Gracenote.

Comment: thanks for your reply! is there another way to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't really a way outside of generating it yourself from some source media (CD or file). Sorry!

Comment: The only Gracenote API that returns track length as of today is when you do a MusicID-Stream query using the mobile SDK.

Comment: Jonx is correct that all streaming queries return the duration of the matched track - including Entourage (ACR), GNSDK's musicid for streaming and Mobile SDK queries.